# Possibilities for $\phi(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Suppose that $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_{20}\to\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ is an automorphism and $\phi(5) = 5$. What are the possibilities for $\phi(x)$?
>
> Because an automorphism $\phi$ maps a generator to a generator, $\phi(1)$ is one of 1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19.  Because $\phi(5) = \phi(5\cdot 1) = 5\phi(1) = 5$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$, the only possible $\phi(1)$ are $1,9,13,17$. Therefore, $\phi(x) = x,9x,13x$, or $17x$.

I understand that an automorphism maps a generator to a generator...and that the possibilies for $\phi(1)$ are one of the elements of $U(20)$. I also understand why $\phi(5)= \dots$.

Can someone please explain why the only possible values of $\phi(1)$ are $1,9,13,17$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must have that $5\phi(1)=5$, but $5 \cdot 3 = 15 \not\equiv 5 \pmod{20}$. You can check similarly that $7, 11, 19$ don't work for the same reason.

Alternatively, notice that $5 \phi(1) \equiv 5 \pmod{20} \iff \phi(1) \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, which immediately rules out $7, 11, 19$.