# Let $\phi:\Bbb{Z}_{20} \to \Bbb{Z}_{20}$ be an automorphism and $\phi(5)=5$. What are the possibilities of $\phi(x)$?

Tags: finite-groups, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

Same question here: [Possibilities for $\phi(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515957/possibilities-for-phix), but I'm striving for a more general solution. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong or if my reasoning is correct.

**Scratch/solution:**
$\phi$ is an isomorphism so $\phi(0)=0$ and every generator of $\Bbb{Z}_{20}$ is mapped to a generator in $\Bbb{Z}_{20}$.
Observation: We want the following properties
\begin{align}
\phi(5)&=\phi(1+1+1+1+1)=5\phi(1)=5 \pmod{20}\\
\phi(5)&=\phi(\sum_{i=1}^{15}3)=\sum_{i=1}^{15}\phi(3)=15\phi(3)=5 \pmod{20}\\
\vdots\\
\text{If} \quad \phi(3)&=1, \text{then}\quad \phi(5)=15\phi(3)=15 \pmod{20}\\
\text{If} \quad \phi(3)&=11, \text{then}\quad \phi(5)=15\phi(3)=15\times 11=165=5\pmod{20}
\end{align}
So I became inclined to find an $\alpha$ such that $15\alpha \equiv5\pmod{20}$, this is in the case of finding a possible image of $\phi(3)$; that is to let $\phi(3)=\alpha$. In general, I noted that for all generators $\gamma\in\Bbb{Z}_{20}$, $\exists k\in\Bbb{Z}_20$ such that $x\equiv \gamma k\pmod{20}$ where $x$ is that arbitrary element of $\Bbb{Z}_{20}$. Which implies $\phi(x)=\phi(\gamma k)=k\phi(\gamma)\pmod{20}$. By finding all $y$ such that $ky \equiv \pmod{20}$ we can let $\phi(\gamma)=y$ and call $\phi(x)=k\phi(y)=ky\pmod{20}$ a possible image of $\phi(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a lot easier to see exactly how flexible the automorphisms are (and count them) if you use $\Bbb Z_{20}\cong \Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_5$, with $5\mapsto (1, 0)$

This is known as the Chinese remainder theorem: If $m, n$ are coprime integers, then $\Bbb Z_{mn}\cong \Bbb Z_m\times \Bbb Z_n$. The most natural isomorphism is $1\mapsto (1, 1)$, so that's the one I'll use here. this gives the $5\mapsto(1, 0)$ above.

An automorphism of $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_5$ must send $(1, 0)$ to an element of order $4$ (i.e. $(1, 0)$ or $(3, 0)$) and it must send $(0,1)$ to an element of order $5$ (i.e. $(0,i)$ for $1\leq i\leq 4$), and any automorphism is uniquely determined by where it sends these two elements.

We want all automorphisms which fix $5\in \Bbb Z_{20}$. That corresponds to automorphisms which fix $(1, 0)$ in $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_5$. That means the only leeway we have is where $(0,1)$ is sent. We have four options, and they all work. Thus the four maps we are after all map $(1,0)$ to $(1,0)$, and then map $(0,1)$ to either one of the four order-$5$ elements $(0,i)$.

In order to translate back to $\Bbb Z_{20}$ I think it's easiest to see what happens to $(1, 1)$: It is sent to some element $(1, i)$ where $1\leq i\leq 4$. Any such choice gives a valid automorphism. Taking our designated isomorphism back to $\Bbb Z_{20}$, we get the following correspondences between automorphisms:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline \text{image of (1, 1)}&\text{image of $1$}\\
\hline
(1, 1) & 1\\
(1, 2) & 17\\
(1, 3) & 13\\
(1, 4) & 9\\\hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: wow. what.. how did you..? why? I don't get it.

Comment: @TheLastCipher I added details. Is it clearer?

Comment: I had a hard time following the explanation, but I eventually did, as I'm not use to thinking of isomorphisms in direct products, yet. I picked your answer since I found your approach interesting. The only thing not clear is the translation back to $\Bbb{Z}_{20}$.

Comment: @TheLastCipher It's the same isomorphism, only in reverse. The map from $\Bbb Z_{20}$ to $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_5$ consists of simply taking $n\mapsto (n\pmod 4, n\pmod 5)$, while the corresponding map from $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_5\to\Bbb Z_{20}$ requires some calculation and solving. To me, it's not "obvious" to find that $(1, 3)$ is mapped to $13$, but it is obvious that $13$ is mapped to $(1, 3)$.

Comment: Sorry for a quite late response. Thank you for clarifying your answer. I now understand. Although, the idea is quite simple, but for me it takes a lot more maturity to possibly emulate your thought process in this. Lastly, if I may ask, why is my procedure incorrect? Thanks!

Comment: @TheLastCipher It does take some practice, but it becomes automatic after a while. My thought process when I saw the problem was something like "fixing 5 means fixing $(1, 0)$, so we can only decide where $(0,1)$ goes" and then I started mentally filling out the table. As to your approach, it was fine when you got to $5\phi(1) \equiv 5$, but I have no idea why you then switched to looking at $\phi(3)$. Clearly, $\phi(1)$ must be a generator, and the generators are $1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19$. Just check what you get when you multiply each of them by $5$, and that would've been it.

Comment: (cont.) In fact, you would only need to check half of them, because $\phi(1) = a$ works if and only if $\phi(1) = -a$ doesn't. So checking $1, 3, 7, 9$ and seeing that $1$ and $9$ work while $3$ and $7$ don't tells you that $11$ and $19$ do not work while $13$ and $17$ do. You could, of course, have done the same with $\phi(3)$ and seen that $3, 7, 11$ and $19$ work. But you shouldn't be afraid to just _check_ when there are so few possibilities. Don't get too focused on finding the solutions theoretically.

Comment: as to why I switched to looking at $\phi(3)$, it is because I was under the idea that the possible values of $\phi(x)$ would vary depending on which generator I choose and to which generator I map the chosen generator to. That does not appear to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

$$5\phi(1) \equiv 5 \pmod{20} \iff \phi(1)\equiv 1 \pmod4 \iff \phi(1)\equiv x \pmod{20} $$
where $x\in \{1, 5, 9, 13, 17\}$. This gives us $5$ automorphisms, each of the form
$$\phi(n) = nx $$

But since $5$ is not a generator of $Z_{20}$ hence $\phi(1)\neq 5$
Hence, $\phi(x)=x,9x,13x,17x$ are the only possibilities.

Comment: I don't get why $\phi(1)\equiv 1 \pmod4 \iff \phi(1)\equiv x \pmod{20} $.

Comment: @TheLast_Cipher sorry for late answer. Numbers that are of the form $4k+1$ for some integer $k$, have to be of the form $20m+x$ for some integer $m$, and $x$ as in the set. This is obvious, when we consider the rests of division $k$ by $5$. Indeed, we just need to consider $5$ different cases. This comes down to a $5$ element arithmetic progression, with difference $4$, and first term $1$

Comment: It's fine. Thank you. I liked your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

We know, an isomorphism maps generators to generators.
Gen Z_20 = {1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19}. These are the possible competitors for automorphisms.
The other condition according to question is Φ(5)=5, say this condition is (C1). To be more accurate Φ(5)=5(mod 20).
Now, Φ(x)=x satisfies C1.
Φ(x)=3x will give Φ(5)=15(mod 20) doesn't satisfies C1.
Φ(x)=7x wil give Φ(5)=15(mod 20) doesn't satisfies C1, and so on.
Eventually we get the automorphisms as x, 9x, 13x, and 17x.